# Winter Bash 2017

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

It's that time of year again. Last year, we participated and enjoy most. Hopefully, There are more fun this year.

For those that don't remember, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

[image]

This event will run up to **3 January 2018**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on [winterbash2017.stackexchange.com](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

[image]

Please comment, add answers below, and/or vote this question up or down (up/down votes on meta mean agree/disagree).

Comment: Can't believe another year has gone by, last year's winner was @AdrianCidAlmaguer

Answer (score 3):

Yes please, we want hats!

[image: Photo of a Druplicon wearing a Santa hat]

Image credit: [Agiledrop](http://drupalsun.com/matic/2017/04/25/agiledrop-drupal-logos-hats)

Answer (score 3):

> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available.

Be aware that at the end of the event the value you selected for that anti-hat option does NOT go back into storage (so that it can be used as the default for next year ...). Instead, every year you MUST re-enable that "I *hate* hats" option (for which I think "I *do not like* hats" would be way more appropriate).

Comment: you are right. But I do not understand why "I hate hats" option is there. If Individual users who don’t want to participate simply do not click on hat link as well. What I think there should not be the "I hate hats" option.

Comment: @Smalution The option is there for users who don't want to be bothered with notifications about new hats they gained or they don't want to see anything in the user interface about hats, which includes also that counter for the new gained hats.

Comment: "*they don't want to see anything in the user interface about hats*", as in the previous comment, is not 100% correct: if you enable that option (= indicate that you *do not like hats*), then still it keeps showing the snowflake (or whatever it is) icon in the top navigation bar (in between the icons for access to review queues and for access to other SE sites).

Comment: The snowflake is quite less intrusive than the rest of the interface added for Winter Bash. If it were just for the snowflake, there would not be an option to opt out from Winter Bash.