# Winter Bash 2018

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

[It's that time of year again](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/). [Last year](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/winter-bash-2017), we participated and enjoyed it. Hopefully, this will [be](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/winter-bash-2016) [as](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3351/winter-bash-2015) [fun](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3146/winter-bash-2014) [as](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/winter-bash-2013) [previous years](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/winter-bash-2012).

For those that don't remember, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

[image: Cats love hats.]

This event starts **12 December 2018** to **2 January 2019**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on [winterbash2018.stackexchange.com](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

[image]

Please comment, add answers below, and/or vote this question up or down (up/down votes on meta mean agree/disagree).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/04/adios-to-winter-bash-2018/

Answer (score 4):

The countdown is on ...

#### Start:

[image: Winter Bash 2018 Start]

#### Stop:

[image: Winter Bash 2018 Start]

Comment: Looks like the countdown had a DST bug in it...

Comment: I suggest you start a new countdown ... to ***2 January 2019*** ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens LMAO this new countdown made my day.

Comment: @NoSssweat really? Because of the colors maybe (I'm from BE, can you tell ...)? BTW who or what is LMAO, do I know him or her, and if so then why not?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens [LMAO](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/lmao-meaning/)

Answer (score 4):

Bring out the hats!

[image: Photo of a Druplicon wearing a Santa hat]

Image credit: [Agiledrop](http://drupalsun.com/matic/2017/04/25/agiledrop-drupal-logos-hats)