# Winter Bash 2019

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

[It's that time of year again](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/). [Last year](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/winter-bash-2018), we participated and enjoyed it. Hopefully, this [will](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/winter-bash-2017) [be](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/winter-bash-2016) [as](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3351/winter-bash-2015) [fun](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3146/winter-bash-2014) [as](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/winter-bash-2013) [previous years](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/winter-bash-2012).

For those that don't remember, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

[image: Cats love hats.]

This event starts **9 December 2019** to **1 January 2020**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on [winterbash2019.stackexchange.com](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

[image]

Please comment, add answers below, and/or vote this question up or down (up/down votes on meta mean agree/disagree).

Comment: Feel free to edit in current screenshots as they become available, or to fix any errors.  Keeping with tradition, I copied last year's post, and edited it.

Comment: psssssssssssst ⏰

Comment: @NoSssweat Sorry, year end deliverables.  Better late than never, https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3861/winter-bash-2020

Answer (score 2):

The countdown has started!

Good luck collecting hats!

[image: Winter Bash 2018 Start]