# Winter Bash 2021

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

[It's that time of year again](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/): On December 15, 2021, Winter Bash will start.
[Last year](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/winter-bash-2020), we participated and enjoyed it. Hopefully, [this](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/winter-bash-2019) [will](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/winter-bash-2018) [be](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3686/winter-bash-2017) [as](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/winter-bash-2016) [fun](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3351/winter-bash-2015) [as](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3146/winter-bash-2014) [the](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/winter-bash-2013) [previous years](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2159/winter-bash-2012).

For those that don't remember, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on [winterbash2021.stackexchange.com](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

Please comment, add answers below, and/or vote this question up or down (up/down votes on meta mean agreement/disagreement).

Comment: Way too difficult this year.